# Applescritp Excel to Find And Replace "

Tags: excel, replace, find, applescript

I need an applescript to find " and replace with just a space.  I found an awesome script on here that works beautifully to find and replace whole words (hello, world) but when you manipulate the script to find " and replace with a space, the " corrupts the code and it no longer works.  I am hoping somebody knows a way to alter this code to make it do what I want or have an other idea.  here is the code (code credit goes to adamh):

```
searchAndReplaceTextInCells("hello", "world")

on searchAndReplaceTextInCells(search_str, replace_str)

tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    set search_range to range "A:Z"
    set all_found_ranges to {} -- store for the ranges, to manipulate after searching
    set found_range to ""
    set counter to 0
    try
        set found_range to find search_range what search_str with match case
    on error
        log ("No matches found")
    end try

    if (found_range is not "") then
        set first_cell_address to (get address of the cells of found_range) -- we use this to break our loop
        repeat while true
            set counter to counter + 1
            copy found_range to end of all_found_ranges

            -- Now look for next result
            set found_range to find next search_range after found_range
            set cell_address to (get address of the cells of found_range)

            if (cell_address = first_cell_address) then 
                -- have looped around so we are finished!
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat

    end if

    -- walk all the ranges found and do the string replacing
    repeat with r in all_found_ranges
        set value of r to my replace_chars(the value of r, search_str, replace_str)
    end repeat

    log ("found and replaced " & counter & " items")
end tell
end searchAndReplaceTextInCells

on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
set my text item delimiters to the search_string
set the item_list to every text item of this_text
set my text item delimiters to the replacement_string
set this_text to the item_list as string
set my text item delimiters to ""
return this_text
end replace_chars
```

Answer (score 0):

As **"** is a reserved character we need to treat it differently when referencing it in strings.

You could use the `quote` constant as your argument:

```
searchAndReplaceTextInCells(quote, " ")
```

..or you could send it in as an escaped character:

```
searchAndReplaceTextInCells("\"", " ")
```